# Install connect web server on RHEL linux with nodejs

Tags: node.js, rhel7, node.js-connect

I have installed nodejs 8.11.3 on RHEL 7.5. Next step is to install the connect web server by running the command **from the nodejs installation directory**.
npm install connect

However, my problem I cannot find the nodejs installation directory in RHEL OS.

As per some suggestion on the internet I ran 
rpm -ql nodejs-8.11.3, but did not establish the nodejs installation directory.

Please advise how to install connect web server to work with nodejs in RHEL.

Thanks
JJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't how Node.js packages work.

You need to run `npm install connect` in the directory **where you want to install the module**.  i.e. in your project directory.

(And you should probably run it with `--save` to update your `package.json` file with the dependency you just added).

Comment: I want to know where the node.js installation directory is. The instructions/documentation says...…..Installing the Web Server
A simple web server will suffice for development, and create one using a Node.js module called Connect. From
within the Node.js installation directory, run the following command:
npm install connect
NPM is the node package installer, and it will pull down the files required for the Connect module. Next, create a
new file called server.js (still within the Node.js installation folder) and set the contents so they match those shown

Comment: @user10118326 — The instructions are wrong. You absolutely should not run that command in the node.js installation directory. You should run it in the directory you are creating your project with.

Comment: There isn't really just a thing as the "node.js installation directory" anyway. Linux packages install files in a number of different places, the node executable itself is likely in `/usr/bin` along with lots of other programs.

Comment: when I run in it any Linux folder, it gives error no such file package.json

Comment: You should create your project before you start adding dependancies to it. https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules